# Filter for specific dates

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table that shows a users registration funnel:

```
user_id   event          date
1         Start   1/1/2018
1         End     1/1/2018
2         Start   1/2/2018
2         End     1/4/2018
etc.
```

I would like to add a "filter" so that I can look at data based on `event=Start` (user registration start date); a `where` clause would not help because if I say `where date between '2/1/2018' and '2/28/2018'`- users that started registration before 2/1/2018 will appear inside the table.

I tried the following:

```
select user_id, event, date
from table
where case when event='Start' then date end between '2/1/2018' and '2/28/2018'
```

But that completes removes the values for `event=End`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select user_id, event, max(case when event='Start' then date else null end) start_date,
max(case when event='End' then date else null end) end_date 
from table
group by user_id, event
```

Comment: `where event=Start` will drop `event=End` similar to what I tried. I am trying to get both events, having `event=Start` be within the date range, so no `event=End` can fire in that date range for a user that registered before it.

Comment: OK try edited answer above - it create a start and end date for each user - u can filter off that then

Comment: Ah this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!